# Não Consigo Clonar um repositorio do git no TFS na minha maquina local

Tags: git

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu sinceramente já estou ficando aborrecido pois estou fazendo o processo do clone corretamente e essa porcaria não funciona, resolvi apelar pra quem realmente sabe, sou iniciante ainda na profissão mais to correndo atrás pra estudar e aprender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `pull` serve para atualizar os dados já existentes na sua máquina, para clonar o repositório você deve usar o clone:

```
$ git clone <url>.git repo
$ cd repo
```

Quando fizer alterações deve primeiro efetuar o `commit` e depois dar o `push`:

```
$ git add <file> <file>
$ git commit -m 'descrição do commit'
$ git push origin master -u
```

Quando se clona o repositório o **origin** é vem configurado.

Para atualizar o repositório em outro PC, use o `pull` (o repositório deve estar previamente clonado).

```
$ git pull origin master
```

Ou em alguns casos

```
$ git pull
```

As vezes o pode não funcionar com o `origin master`, isso também vale para o `push` (Experiencia própria).

> Caso mais de uma pessoa use o repositório, sempre de um `pull` antes de dar o `push`.

Comment: OK obrigado, mais o problema era outro tive que adicionar credenciais ao repositório do TFS pra poder baixar o projeto obrigado.